# what does this expression do for(d=0;d<n-c-1;d++) {Bubble sort}

Tags: c

I was trying to figure out how the inner loop works in this below code but I couldn't understand. The part that I really struggle to understand is this condition part `(d<n-c-1)` // inner for loop//

```
include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int array[100], n, c, d, swap;

  printf("Enter number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

  for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++) {

    for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {

      if (array[d] > array[d + 1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        swap = array[d];
        array[d] = array[d + 1];
        array[d + 1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  return 0;
```

Comment: You *do* know how `for` loops work? You have an initialization, a condition, and an "increment". Which part is it you have trouble with?

Comment: Its a condition part that I don't understand

Comment: It's a normal condition, it's almost the same as the outer loop condition. Would it help if it was written `d < (n - c - 1)`? I also recommend you learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what happens, and see what values you have. Then you could add a watch to see what the value of `n - c - 1` is, and see how the comparison with `d` would be.

Comment: Well thanks for your tip

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is a compare loop for a bubblesort. It makes sure that the last position in the array is the highest one. The next loop for c, it checks all elements but the last one (that one is already sorted).

Example:

```
0 1 2 3 4 (index of array)
5 3 4 2 1 (start, c=0, d=0)
3 5 4 2 1 (start, c=0, d=1)
3 4 5 2 1 (start, c=0, d=2)
3 4 2 5 1 (start, c=0, d=3)
3 4 2 1 5 (start, c=0, d=4)
```

The next loop, c will be 1 and d will only increase to 3. This will leave the highest value (5) on the highest index (4).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the outer loop loops c from 0 to n-1;

- When c is 0, the inner loop loops d from 0 to n-1
- when c is 1, the inner loop loops d from 0 to n-2
- when c is 2, the inner loop loops d from 0 to n-3

etc.

Graphically:

```
 *********
 ******** 
 *******
 ******
 *****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a `Bubble Sort` algorithm. The first loop `for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)` is the number of main iteration it needs to complete the sort and the second for loop `for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)` is to set the limit of how many compare and swap is needed.

For the first iteration it should compare and swap the whole array, the second iteration is to the `"end of array - 1"` and so forth.

You can see a nice visualization [here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html).

Comment: Thanks . now it make sense

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your question, its about the condition part of this `for` loop:

```
for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {}
```

Condition is : `d < n - c - 1`  which is same as `d < (n - c - 1)`

which means this `for` loop will execute till `d` is less than `(n - c - 1)`